# How to send JSON into a WEBAPI that uses a model as inputParam from the HTTPPOST

Tags: c#, json.net

I have defined a model for my input parameter in my HTTP POST method like this

```
public ActionResult<JObject> Post([FromBody] APIInputObject apiInputObject)
```

The Model looks like this

```
public class APIInputObject
{
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
    public Brand Brand { get; set; }
    public string Query { get; set; }
    public string Locale { get; set; } = "SE";
    public string UseFormatter { get; set; }
}
```

The Brand part is further defined like this

```
public class Consumer
{
    public string ConsumerName { get; set; }
    public List<Brand> Brands { get; set; }
}

public class Brand
{
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is now that when I send JSON is that looks like below I get an error

```
{
    "apiKey": "xxx",
    "Brand": "xx",
    "query": "showBrand"
}
```

The error is as follows

```
{
    "errors": {
        "Brand": [
            "Error converting value \"xx\" to type 'Pim.Models.Brand'. Path 'Brand', line 3, position 17."
        ]
},
```

What can I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original JSON formatting is wrong it should be in the following format:

```
{
    "apiKey": "xxx",
    "Brand": {
        "BrandName": "xx"
    },
    "query": "showBrand"
}
```

Bonus help, for your consumer object your json format would be like so:

```
{
    "ConsumerName": "xxx",
    "Brands": [{
        "BrandName": "xx1"
    },
    {
        "BrandName": "xx2"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Note to self, stop coding at midnight :)